# Database - create trigger

Tags: database, postgresql

I create the view in my database where I have item_id and reservation_id where their start_date_of_reservation > current_date or end_date_of_reservation < current_date (it means that there are items which are now available to reserve). Now I want to create trigger which will be update this view once a day or a week in the same way. I don't know how do this. Should I always delete this view and create once again with the same conditions to do my view with only available items? Is it possible to run trigger once a day or a week?

Answer (score 1):

A regular view will pull from underlying tables and so will automatically show the changes to them. If you have a materialized view that is another thing. In any case you can't have a trigger fire on a time schedule. If you are using a materialized view you can update using some sort of script. As mentioned before a regular view will automatically pick up changes to the tables it depends on.